# How can I improve performance in my forward substitution method for lower triangle matrices?

Tags: python, scipy

I tried implementing the forward substitution method, a solving process to solve the problem Lx = b with L being a lower triangle matrix and x,b as vectors.

This was an easy task:

```
def tri_solve(L,b):
    n = len(b)
    x = np.zeros(n)
    x[0] = b[0]/L[0,0];

    for i in range(1,n):
        comp = 0;
        for k in range(0,i):
            index = L[i,k]
            preSolution = x[k]
            comp = comp + index * preSolution
        x[i] = 1/L[i,i] * (b[i] - comp)
    return x;
```

Now I compared my calculation times for different sized matrices several times with  linalg.solve from the scipy module and it turns out that it is much faster. This makes sense in some points, since SciPy is written in C and C++, but I still expected similar or better calculation times for matrices up to 10x10 dimension. Beginning with 6x6 matrices, linalg.solves becomes slightly faster on average.

Is there a way to improve my rather simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [solve_triangular](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_triangular.html)

If you want to accelerate your code, what you could do is to vectorize the inner loop.

```py
def tri_solve(L,b):
    n = len(b)
    x = np.zeros(n)
    x[0] = b[0]/L[0,0];

    for i in range(1,n):
        comp = np.sum(L[i,:i] * x[:i])
        x[i] = 1/L[i,i] * (b[i] - comp)
    return x;
```

###### Edit: How to use it

You have to pass as first argument a square lower triangular matrix and as second argument you can pass a 1D array

```py
N = 20
A = np.tril(np.random.randn(N, N))
b = np.random.randn(N)
assert np.allclose(np.linalg.solve(A, b), tri_solve(A, b))
```

Of course this is a naive implementation and is not stable, you can't use it to solve very large or ill conditioned systems.

Comment: This throws an exception

Comment: Probably have an unusual input, I edited the answer with an example.